# Replacing 3-way Light Switch Confusion

Tags: switch, basement, light

I am trying to replace a switch that stop turning off the lights in basement (controls 6 lights).

It seems to be a 3-way switch so I bought a new one that supports 3-way but then I got confused by looking at the set up on old switch (wires #1 and 2 are going inside and #3 is wrapping around a screw as shown here.

[image]

I am not sure how these wires will go in the new switch that has 4 options marked on new switch picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where you see a back-stabbed wire, it is internally connected to the adjacent screw. You photo seems to show the two bottom wires going to the same terminal which seems to imply a normal 2-way switch, not a 3-way. Can you get a new photo of the old switch with the back turned more to the camera?

Comment: Thanks so much. I will provide a pic of old switch shortly.

Comment: [Pic 1](https://imgur.com/JCHQtLH), [Pic 2](https://imgur.com/kZcyldY), [Pic 3](https://imgur.com/U0fYEQX), [Pic 4](https://imgur.com/uM6PIZu)

Comment: From those photos, that is definitely a standard two-way switch with the bottom two wires internally joined. There is no way that can be a 3-way switch.

Answer (score 1):

With some help from others, we concluded the old switch is simple 2 way switch, not a 3 way switch.

It has 2 wires connected to same terminal.

If it is no longer working just replace it with normal switch with same wiring as the old switch.

Comment: no, that's not right.  OP's original switch is not a 3-way.

Comment: OP misidentified it, common mistake. it's a normal 1-way with both backstabs and 1 screw used.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will provide a pic of old switch shortly.

Comment: [Pic 1](https://imgur.com/JCHQtLH), [Pic 2](https://imgur.com/kZcyldY), [Pic 3](https://imgur.com/U0fYEQX), [Pic 4](https://imgur.com/uM6PIZu)

Comment: @raazk thank you for the pic, still we think it is a regular switch not 3 way. Final test/question: can you control (on/off) the garage lights from another switch ?

Comment: Thanks so much @Ruskes. I will get the 2-way switch today. Garage setup is completely different actually (connected with garage opener).